# Java - Put Threads and other Objects that extend the same Class is an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, 2d-games

I'm making an event-based game (basically, there is no while(true) loop: if there is no event, no code lines are getting executed). The game is based with room objects, each room has an ArrayList who contains monsters and loot objects.

The problem is that I need the monsters to be Threads, so they will automaticly launch events in the game (like following the player and attacking him).

The motherclass of Monsters and Loot is the same: GameObject. As I spend a lot of time doing the game this way (one list for loots and monsters) I'm wondering if there is a way to let the two objects monster and loots in the same list and still having the monsters as Threads.

For the moment I use the "implements Runnable" method. I don't know if it is the best way.

Thank you.

Edit:

Here's the code. First the motherclass, GameObjects

```
public abstract class GameObjects {

protected int x;
protected int y;
private int height;
private int width;
private Player player; //And then there are all getters and setters.

}
```

Then the Monster class, there are various monsters, like zombies.

```
package game.projetdonjon;

public abstract class Monster extends GameObjects implements Runnable {

private char direction;
private int hp;
private boolean alive;
private Player player;

public void getDamage(int p){
    this.hp=p;
    if (this.pv <= 0) {
        this.alive = false;
        System.out.println("The monster is death.");
    }
}

public boolean isAlive() {
    if (isAlive)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
//And then still others getters & setters...
}
```

The Zombie Class:

```
package game.projetdonjon;

public class Zombie extends Monster implements Runnable {

private Thread thread;
private int hp;

public Zombie(int x, int y,Player player) {
    super.setDirection('E');
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.hp = 50;
    this.thread = new Thread();
    super.setHeight(50);
    super.setWidth(50);
    super.setHp(hp);
    super.setAlive(true);
    super.setPlayer(player);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Zombie's runnig, yo!");
    while (true) {
        this.setX(this.getX()+10);
        try {
            thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Finally, the Room Class, it contains the monsters and loot.

```
package game.projetdonjon;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Room {
private ArrayList<GameObjects> roomElements = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<Door> roomDoors= new ArrayList();
private int roomNumber;

public Piece(int roomNumber){
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    roomElements.add(new Loot(somearguments...));
    roomEleemnts.add(new Thread(new Zombie(50,50,player))); //Here is the 
//problem, as Thread isn't a GameObjects/ doesn't extend GameObjects

}
```

Comment: while you have written a good question; it will be hard to answer without an actual problem and/or code sample demonstrating the issue experienced

Comment: Also you might be careful about quantity of monster and clearing them up when you create 30 monster you will have performance issues and you will have to redesign again

Answer (score 1):

Runnable implementing is the best way.
But I recommend to do two Lists for your room object: first List contains monsters (Runnables), second List contains loot.

Comment: Obviously, this is the best way. But I spent a lot of time coding the game as the two objects were in the same list. So if I have no other choice I will do that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To have this two classes in an ArrayList you can create an interface say IGameObjects and let the two classes implement it.

```
public interface IGameObjects {

    public void method(); //common method.
}
```

And then you can have

```
List<GameObjects> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside your GameObject class.

Then you can handle them inside a loop:

```
for (IGameObjects object : gameObjects) {
    object.method();
}
```